# Questions about IIS and localhost

Tags: windows, visual-studio, iis, localhost

I have some really basic questions about IIS and accessing localhost when testing a project in VS. When I test a web application through Visual Studio 2012, it launches an IIS service and the website launches in Chrome with url

`http://localhost:23456/home.aspx`

I wanted to see if I could access it on the same computer but externally on another tab using

`http://<myexternalWANIP>:23456/home.aspx`

(where **myexternalWANIP** is my IP address) but I keep getting a Chrome message `Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to <myexternalWANIP>:23456`

I've then shutdown VS2012 and assumed the files would still be available using `http://localhost:23456/home.aspx` but this now gives the same error.

So my questions are

1. How do I test the web application on localhost without opening VS2012?
2. Is it possible to access the site using `http://<myexternalWANIP>:23456/home.aspx` if testing through VS?
3. Assuming I get 1. working, is it possible to access the site using `http://<myexternalWANIP>:23456/home.aspx` when I'm using the same computer and same IP address or does this only work when accessing externally?
4. If 3. is not possible, would it work through TOR for instance where I'd be routing from another IP address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I test the web application on localhost without opening VS2012?

You should install (if none) IIS on your local machine, create a web application and deploy your built application there.

> Is it possible to access the site using http://:23456/home.aspx if testing through VS?

Open web project settings, on tab 'Web' you should select "Use Custom Web server" option.

> is it possible to access the site using http://:23456/home.aspx when I'm using the same computer and same IP address or does this only work when accessing externally?

Configure your router to redirect request on specific port to your machine with IIS installed.

> If 3. is not possible, would it work through TOR for instance where I'd be routing from another IP address?

It should work if point 3 works.